# Force webpage to exist at '/'?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to have a URL like:

```
http://example.com//
```

I know that the 'forward slash' at the end is invalid (becasue a page cannot be named: '/' or can it?) - but is there a way, by using .htaccess to force a webpage to exist at that location (other than the index page).

So, `http://example.com/` is the index page, but when users type: `http://example.com//` they get another webpage.

You see, my issue is that I need a 'one character' page - and to keep consistency the '/' is the best.

(I know that this is not recommended: perhaps sparking a negative reaction - but, for interest, I am seeing if this is possible - a .htaccess solution will be great.)

Comment: `/` means root usually and in directory paths. Most browsers will ignore additional slashes such as `//`. That is not a good way to do anything. Why not use a letter or number? or maybe a dash. Don't use something that already has a specific purpose in URLs. That makes no sense. You should come up with another way.

Comment: Because everyone uses letters/numbers/punctuation - it needs to be different!

Comment: @Sk9TSFVBQkVBTA: So it could be something else than a number/letter/`/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way you can do this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s//[\s?]
RewriteRule ^ another-page.php [L]
```

This will show `/index.php` for `http://example.com/` and show `/another-page.php` for `http://example.com//`.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked. However, there is an issue: how can I link to this page via the index page? Currently, I have: '<a href=/>' this goes to the index - but if (to continue your example) I want to link the 'another-page.php' [<a href=another-page.php>], in the HTML of the index page - but, - this goes to the page but in the address bar it has: 'another-page.php' - so, simply, I want a loop: on the index: <a href=//>, then on this page I want a link back to the index: <a href=/>. The issue is that I want relative URL's - not absolute URL's - is this possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can this work for a number of '/' - if for example, I want my CSS file to be located at: '///' - is this possible? You see, don't you think it would be great if the HTML is '/', then a page is: '//', then the CSS: '///', then an icon: '////' - can this be done? so: <link rel=icon href=////>

Comment: No `<a href=//>` won't work because browsers don't like just `//` in links. Same thing is with `///` and `////`

Comment: How about a '\', so it will go from '/' to '\' then to: '/' again. The URL's need to be relative though...

Comment: Even `<a href=\\>` or `<a href=\>` are not accepted by browsers